# Starting EasterEgg intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

how can I start EASTER EGG intent from Android application?

I can start Easter Egg intent using ADB command:

```
adb shell am start -n android/com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity
```

but I can't start that intent from my application, any way?

here's my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android/com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

here's the LogCat:

```
06-20 15:25:54.466: W/System.err(965): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity }
06-20 15:25:54.476: W/System.err(965):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
06-20 15:25:54.476: W/System.err(965):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-20 15:25:54.476: W/System.err(965):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-20 15:25:54.476: W/System.err(965):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-20 15:25:54.476: W/System.err(965):  at awaisking.testapp.itdunya.MainClass$1.onClick(MainClass.java:41)
```

Comment: have you tryed just "com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity"?

Comment: yes, It doesn't work!

Comment: You can't start it unless calling process is running in system uid

Comment: @shoerat yes, i know, but any way to start that process with command line?

Comment: what do you mean by "command line"?

Comment: terminal command line

Comment: like in cmd (adb shell am start -n android/com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity)?

Comment: adb runs with special privileges, you can't start PlatLogoActivity without such permissions. If I really have to have that screen on my app, I'd (re-)implement it locally within my app.

Comment: k, thnx for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct intent is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("android", "com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity");
```

But even with this, you won't be able to start the activity due to security restrictions.